# Externalize pdf_tex like externalize tikz

Tags: pdf, tex-core, tikz-external

I am using the workflow explained in this tutorial for typesetting images in my document: [Tutorial for pdf_tex using inkscape](http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/inkscape-images-with-latex-fonts/)
Briefly, a vector image is imported into inkscape and then image itself is saved as pdf with figure labels removed and figure labels along with their positions are saved as a separate pdf_tex file. Finally that pdf_tex file is used inside figure environment. It results in perfect consistency between document and figure label fonts. The MWE can be found from the link provided along with the necessary files.

Now the problem is that many journals require labelled pdf files to be directly imported in the main tex document. I can do so by manually saving each figure separately but I am looking for something like "tickz externalize" to generate pdf files separately with correct font so that after compiling once, they may be directly used in the main document at the submission stage. Any thing like "pdf_tex externalize"? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When tikz externalizes a tikzpicture it basically copies all its contents into a new .tex document, which is compiled using the `standalone` class. So you can manually do the same thing for your incscape picture. Just create a new tex document with following content

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\input{your_incscape_file_goes_here.pdf_tex}
\end{document}
```

When you compile this document, you will probably get an error. I could resolve it by deleting `width=\unitwidth` in the *.pdf_tex file. After success compiling this document you can include the resulting pdf in your main document.

**EDIT:** There is also a very hacky solution, using the externalize function of tikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{YourIncscapeFile.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I assumed that your article will have two columns, that's why I used `\columnwidth` instead of `\textwidth`.

Remark: this gives you just the image without the text, which you have to manually place with some `\node` constructions afterwards. But this method guarantees that text will always have the correct size.

Comment: Hi thanks manthano. But, when I do exactly as suggested by you, it does not result in a pdf file in the working directory. It does compile correctly, and shows correctly in the document. However, I do not find the resulting pdf file from pdf_tex file which I will have to include in the main document.

Comment: @Mist do you compile using pdflatex?

Comment: Yes! I am using texstudio and pdflatex

Comment: @Mist  then, in that case, the resulting pdf should be in the same folder as this little "script". There is no other way then manually doing this for all your incscape files

Comment: Hello, I have got the pdf now. But now there is another problem. I have no control over size of pdf. I can't reduce it or increase it. One of the reasons that I use pdf_latex functionality: I can control the size of figure while keeping the size of texts same. So following this method does not fulfill that primary purpose, I am afraid. Or perhaps, I am missing something?

Comment: @Mist in your main  document you probably want to include the resulting pdf with `\includegraphics[width=WhateverYouWant]{img}`. Here you can set the size. Since you include a vector graphic, which is always scaleable as you want, there is no need to specify a size before.

Comment: you are right but unfortunately that makes the font too small as compared to the picture. There should be a reasonable size ratio of font and graphics, isn't it?

Comment: For example see this screenshot of the output. http://s15.postimg.org/f57kwfv6j/image.png

Comment: @Mist Ahh, I see. Basically you have two options: either you manipulate your .pdf_tex file, search for the places where the text is inserted and manually scale it (this is the bad solution since this requires to much manual scaling), or, which basically renders all our previous effort worthless, you copy the `\begin{picture}..\end{picture}` part from your pdf_tex file into your main document, where you placed your `\includegraphic` before. Here you can set the width to whatever fit your needs. Since the text is now placed in your main document, the font size should fit the rest of the document

Comment: But if I do the latter, that will bring me back to square one :(. You know, I wanted to have a procedure using which I will get pdf pictures correctly labelled according to main document formatting and then before submitting it to a journal, I simply replace pdf_tex files with correctly labelled pdf files. I hope, now my question is clearer than earlier?

Comment: can you please provide me with a MWE of tikz externalize? I want to try pasting the "pdf_tex" code instead of standard tikz code inside a tikzpicture environment and lets see how it turns out. Thank you very much

Comment: @Mist I edited my answer. Please check if everything works now as wanted

Comment: Hi, I think I finally found the solution to this problem. It is pretty simple now. Just use standalone package instead of standalone class. I have marked your answer as accepted. You might want to edit it to include this solution. Thanks